# Location aware search

Tags: lucene, solr

I am trying location aware search with spatial example found in
http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/java/library/j-spatial/#indexing.approaches.

The `schema.xml` has a geohash field, but this field is not present in any of the .osm files (present in data folder) used to index. I am not able to understand how the value is assigned to it, so that when I give this query

```
http://localhost:8983/solr/select/?q=_val_:"recip (ghhsin(geohash(44.79, -93), geohash, 3963.205), 1, 1, 0)"^100
```

result set has geohash value retrieved. How is it happening? Please help me.

Comment: Official spatial search will be released with Solr 1.5. You could use JTeam's plugin in the meantime: http://www.jteam.nl/news/spatialsolr.html

Comment: Am currently using Solr 1.5 Nightly build,but the link says ssp is compatible with Solr 1.4. Do i have to go with solr1.4 only?

Comment: I have no idea. SSP is not as flexible as the upcoming spatial support, but it certainly works *right now*, it's simple to use, and it's well documented.

Comment: If you want to try a different approach you could use Local Solr.. Here's a link on how to get it running with Solr 1.4 http://www.craftyfella.com/2009/12/installing-localsolr-onto-solr-14.html

Answer (score 2):

The Solr wiki has a pretty good page on how Spatial search can be done with solr 1.5+.

To summarize, your schema defines 'geohash' typed fields:

```xml
<fieldtype name="geohash" class="solr.GeoHashField"/>
<field name="destination" type="geohash" indexed="true" stored="true"/>
```

Data feeders pass in geohashed coordinates:

```xml
<field name="destination">cbj1pb56p4b</field> <!-- 45.17614 -93.87341 -->
```

You probably should go back to using simple latitude and longitude coordinates to start off with. There are better docs for it.